# cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (4,3)

Tags: machine-learning, python, pandas, lstm

I have a dataset with three inputs X1,X2,X3. I tried to predict next value of X1 using lstm .
I wrote the code for lstm and while trying model.predict I got an error `cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (4,3)`

Here my code:

```
data= pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['X1','X2','X3','X4']) 
data.columns = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3','X4']
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
data = data.dropna ()
y=data['Y'].astype(int)
cols=['X1', 'X2', 'X3','X4']
x=data[cols].astype(int)

data=data.values
scaler_x = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
x = np.array(x).reshape ((len(x),4 ))
x = scaler_x.fit_transform(x)
scaler_y = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range =(0, 1))
y = np.array(y).reshape ((len(y), 1))
y = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)

train_end = 80
x_train=x[0: train_end ,]
x_test=x[train_end +1: ,]
y_train=y[0: train_end]
y_test=y[train_end +1:] 
x_train=x_train.reshape(x_train.shape +(1,))
x_test=x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))    

num_time_steps=3
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(num_time_steps,x_train_n.shape[2])))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True))  # returns a sequence of vectors of dimension 32
model.add(LSTM(8))  # return a single vector of dimension 32
model.add(Dense(1))


batchsize = 1
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",optimizer="adam")
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train, batch_size = batchsize, nb_epoch=30,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),shuffle =True)

model.reset_states()
pred1=model.predict(x_test)

pred1 = []
for s in x_train:
   pred1.append(model.predict(s[0].reshape(x_train.shape[2], num_time_steps)))
   pred1 = np.array(pred1)
```

Error :
[image: Error]

[MY CSV FILE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Show all code, especially when you create x_train. I supposed that you trying transform flat 4-element array into array with 3 dimension.

Comment: @Paweł I upload my full code , now you may can look at it . Thank you

Comment: @Paweł no I have four elements and one output